# SQL Server integration service catalog missing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I Installed SSMA and integration service catalog missing

[image]

integration service missing in sql server config mge too

[image]

Comment: When using SSMS choose "Integration Services" on the connection dialog instead of "SQL Server".

Comment: Migration Assistant (SSMA) has nothing to do with SSIS. This screenshot is from Configuration Manager, a completely unrelated tool. SSMS itself is a client tool, it doesn't install any feature on the server. Have you checked the [SSIS Installation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services) ?

Comment: You'll find information on what the catalog is, and how to create it in the [Create the SSIS Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15#create-the-ssis-catalog) section in the [SSIS Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the integration services feature is enabled when installing SQL Server.

Comment: Enabling SSIS won't install the *catalog*

Comment: I know but not having the integration service in the sql server configuration manager is indicative of a feature not installed, he cant have the catalog withour the feature.

Comment: No it's not. The SSIS catalog is a database that has to be created and configured explicitly. Its location, high-availability configuration etc can't be determined during installation, or set to defaults.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know that, thanks for the info (y)

Answer (score 0):

Installed Developer Version instead of express version. hence issue resolved

Comment: You asked about the **catalog**, not the SSIS service itself. You *still* have to create the catalog. You didn't explain that you're using SQL Server Express either. If you check [the SSIS features by edition page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in the docs you'll see that SSIS itself is available from Standard and up. Express only offers the Import/Export wizard through SSMS.